# Parse File Name for Client Name and Email Address

Tags: email, applescript

I currently have a script that will create a new email in Airmail 2 and then send this email to a predefined recipient name and email address.  I would like to update the script so that it will parse the name of the file passed to it (which is attached to the email) and pull the client name and the client email address from the file name.  The files that will be passed to this script have names that contain both the name of the client to whom the attachment needs to be emailed and the client's email address (e.g., "FirstN LastN—2015-12-28—client@example.com.pdf").

Conveniently, the file names are formatted in such a way that both the client name and the email address are set off (respectively at the beginning and at the end of the file name) by a "—".

Here is the script in its current form:

```
set theAttachment1 to (POSIX path of theFile)
set clientName to item 1 of inputAttributes
set clientEmail to item 1 of inputAttributes
tell application "Airmail 2"
    activate
    set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:"New Invoice", content:"Please find attached, infra, the current month's invoice."}
    tell theMessage
        set sender to "billing@example.com"
        make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {name:"clientName", address:"clientEmail"}
        make new mail attachment with properties {filename:theAttachment1}
        sendmessage
    end tell
end tell
```

The second and third lines are the ones that need to be updated.  I am uncertain of how precisely to pull just the bit before the "—" and set clientName to that value and how to pull the bit after the *second* "—" and set clientEmail to that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use the applescript text item delimiters. the script bellow is parsing the FileName into the name and address, after removing the file extension :

```
set FileName to "FirstN LastN—2015-12-28—client@example.com.pdf"

-- remove the extension (last item when separated by ".")
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "."
set Myitems to every text item of FileName
set last text item of Myitems to ""
set FileName to Myitems as text

-- parse the name with the "—"
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "—"
set myName to first text item of FileName
set myAddress to last text item of FileName
```

The variable myName will be "FirstN LastN".

The variable myAddress will be "client@exemple.com".

Comment: With a little tweaking, this seems to have worked.  For any future searchers: The biggest change I had to make was removing the path from FileName: `-- remove path from FileName
 set text item delimiters to ":"
 set FileName to last text item of (theFile as text)
`